# async function: can I return before await was executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, babeljs

I have a function in which I want to test a condition before running any async code. If the condition is not met, I want to return with an error. I'm trying to run something like this:

```
async function myFunc(req, res, next) {
  if (condition) {
    return res.status(400).json({message: "condition not met"})
  }
  await something();
  res.json({});
}
```

But my await function is still called. Babel transpiles it to this:

```
"use strict";

var myFunc = function () {
  var _ref = _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee(req, res, next) {
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            if (!condition) {
              _context.next = 2;
              break;
            }

            return _context.abrupt("return", res.status(400).json({ message: "condition not met" }));

          case 2:
            _context.next = 4;
            return something();

          case 4:
            res.json({});

          case 5:
          case "end":
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee, this);
  }));

  return function myFunc(_x, _x2, _x3) {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}();

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { function step(key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) { step("next", value); }, function (err) { step("throw", err); }); } } return step("next"); }); }; }
```

As you see, after the if condition, the code breaks and continues the cycle to the next phase. I don't know if it's a Babel issue, or if this is how it's supposed to work. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: _"But my await function is still called"_ The `condition` is evaluated as `false`

Comment: Your description and the 1st snippet seem to disagree with each other… "*If the condition is not met, I want to return with an error.*" vs. `if (condition) { return ...; }`. – The code is returning when `condition` is *truthy*. Babel just inverts it to `return` when negating `condition` results in `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my await function is still called.

No, it isn't, `_context.next` will never be 2 in your situation where `condition` is truthy. `case 0` clearly says to go to state 2 (calling `something`) if `!condition` and to do `return _context.abrupt` otherwise. Your code says to return early if `condition`. That's the same thing, just the other way around.

If the condition is true, your code will indeed return before `await something()` is excuted, and `await something()` will never be executed in that case. (Note that `myFunc` returns a promise anyway, it's just that the promise it returns will already be resolved with the return value of `res.status(400).json({message: "condition not met"})` (presumably `undefined`).

> If the condition is not met, I want to return with an error.

That's not what your code says. Your code says "if the condition **is** met, return with an error:"

```
if (condition) {
  return res.status(400).json({message: "condition not met"})
}
```

Comment: You are so right, and I was so wrong. I missed that my condition wasn't true, and in between debugging this for hours, I was sure that I saw that it is and got stuck there. Sometimes you need a good bang on the head.

Answer (score 0):

You can invert `condition` and use an `else` statement

```
async function myFunc(req, res, next) {
  if (!condition) {
    return res.status(400).json({message: "condition not met"})
  } else {
    await something();
    return res.json({});
  }
}
```

Comment: They could. It would be completely pointless, and doesn't address the heart of the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not sure what you mean? The Answer does address the Question. The description of expected result is contrary to the logic used at code at Question to get that result _"If the condition is not met, I want to return with an error."_